# Why does SSH server say, "authorized_keys is not a regular file"?

Tags: freebsd, sshd

I've been trying to configure the login with a key generated from puttygen so I can disable password authentication.

I saved a private key from puttygen and copied the public part to my .ssh/authorized_keys like so:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza[...]1qRQ==
```

Here's what I changed in my sshd_config

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePAM no
```

But every time I try to login with my key the server refuses it..

[image]

Log:

```
error: key_read: type mismatch: encoding error
sshd[735]: error: key_from_blob: can't read key type
sshd[735]: error: key_read: key_from_blob
User root authorized keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a regular file
```

`stat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` says:

```
68 3451018 drw------- 2 root wheel 6903510 512 "Jan 28 18:12:08 2016" "Jan 28 17:40:50 2016" "Jan 28 17:46:22 2016" "Jan 28 17:40:42 2016" 32768 8 0 /root/.ssh/.authorized_keys
```

Using FreeBSD 9.3

Comment: The "not a regular file" confuses me. What does `stat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` say?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9YsRNy5.png  (hard to read in the comments)

Comment: That looks like it's a directory? It should be a file, at least for openssh, where each line is like the one you give in your post, i.e. corresponds to one keypair.

Comment: @JoãoMonteiro Welcome to Unix & Linux.  Just a tip: when a comment asks for more information, it's best to edit the original question to add the information (as text, if at all possible) rather than putting it in a comment.  This can be done even once your question has been answered.

Comment: Did the `stat` command really say the name was `/root/.ssh/.authorized_keys`? There is a `.` too much in there, and I don't see how that could possibly have happened if the `stat` command was in fact typed without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Ulrich Schwarz, `.ssh/authorized_keys` must be a regular file.  In your case, it looks like it's a directory.  You need to remove the directory and create a single text file with the key in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the keys generated by puttygen to be troublesome in almost every attempt I made. I am not exactly sure why and how, but the format of the file it generates is not accepted by my Linux and other legacy UNIX systems.

My suggestion is, once you are on the server, generate keys using command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

enter pass phrase if you want and file names and location too. Then append the public key generated to the end of authorized keys file. Copy (ftp or scp) private key to your PC. Open puttygen and use the import a key option. And on your putty interface, use the newly imported key.

This approach worked for me all the time

Comment: While key formats can be an issue, I don't think this answer is relevent because the OP shows that he used the correct key format: `ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza[...]1qRQ==`